# Convert list of strings into existing variables

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, variables

I wanted to know how to convert a list of string into existing variables

Example :

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))


def user_data(user_id, gst, total, uname, adress, service, quantity):
    uyt = ['gst', 'total', 'uname', 'adress' 'service', 'quantity'] 
    for r in uyt:
        d[user_id][r]= r // where i want to pass it 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_data(1234, '8', "2345", 'mock', 'mumbai', 'fedx', '4' )
```

Comment: I recommend reading the answers in that dupe, especially `**kwargs`. Use the dict to index.

Comment: If you're not able to adapt any of those answers, feel free to edit your question with what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: The indention in your source does not look like it is working.

Comment: Can you please tell me the answer in more detail ??/